# Getting this error in R about non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix

```
#Error in grassland.data[n + ((y - 1) * 8), 6] * grassland.data[n + ((y -  : 
#  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I am trying to write a for loop.

```
(input.filename="CO_Grassland_Area.csv", nyears=3, nstrata=8, iseed=430983, nreps = 10000)


SOC.stock<- matrix(0, nrow =nstrata*nyears, ncol = 3)

for (y in (1:nyears)){
  for (n in (1:nstrata)){
    SOC.stock[n+((y-1)*8),]<- grassland.data[n+((y-1)*8),6]*
                               grassland.data[n+((y-1)*8),16]*
                              grassland.data[n+((y-1)*8),8]*
                              grassland.data[n+((y-1)*8),10] 


  }
}
```

`

Comment: It seems that one of your grassland.data is not numeric; try wrap each grassland.data around `as.numeric` like:  `var1 <- as.numeric(grassland.data[n + ((y - 1) * 8), 6])`.

Comment: Post output of `str(grassland.data)` as [edit]to body of question.